# Destructor ends before completing its task in C#?

Tags: c#, input, destructor

The following *destructor* code in *desctructorCheck* class closes the console, after almost 2 seconds, before getting any input from user.

```
~destructorCheck() {
   Console.WriteLine("Destructor");
   Console.ReadLine( );
}
```

Why it is closing?
Do *destructor* have any timer to finish its cleanup process?

Comment: You should read Eric Lippert's blog posts on [finalizers](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/)

Comment: Related: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/finalizers-at-process-exit.html

Comment: @all Thanks for your quicky understandable responses and for your referrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Finalizers have a limited amount of time to run before they will be terminated.

This is one of the many reasons that finalizers are a tool of last resort. They aren't guaranteed to run in the first place, and not guaranteed to finish. They are only running because the Framework really needs that object to go away *now* -- it's either GC'ing it because it needs memory, or your application is shutting down.

I'm pretty sure the time limit is ~2 seconds, and I don't know of any way to change it.

Comment: I wouldn't change it if I could!

Comment: Nor would I, but that's usually the immediate follow-up question from people who really want to misuse them. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, because of how Destructors are called:

To quote MSDN:

> 'The programmer has no control over when the destructor is called
>   because this is determined by the garbage collector. The garbage
>   collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the
>   application. If it considers an object eligible for destruction, it
>   calls the destructor (if any) and reclaims the memory used to store
>   the object. Destructors are also called when the program exits.'

I agree that reading Eric Lippert's blog is a good thing!

If you need to ensure something happens when your C# object is being destroyed, you should probably implement IDisposable and put your closure logic into the Dispose method.

Comment: That is an unfortunately misleading bit of text from MSDN, as it implies that first, the GC calls the destructor during tracing, and second, that destruction reclaims memory. A more accurate description would be that the GC identifies finalizable objects and *keeps them alive for the finalizer thread to deal with*.